# how to return a dynamic char array from function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I dont really understand pointers and how to call and create dynamic arrays despite spending the time to educate myself on them and I am running into an error on the following line:

```
char *dArray = alphabet(N);
```

Here on my instructions and what Im trying to do:

1. The program first asks user to enter the number of elements for an array. Let’s call this number N.
2. It then creates a dynamic array of size N+ 1, containing Nrandom lowercase alphabet letters between
   ‘a’ and ‘z’. Make sure the last element is a null character ‘\0’.
   – Here, make sure to use dynamic memory allocation (using new command) to allocate memory
   space for the array, which is exactly why we call it a dynamic array.
3. After creating the array, the program displays the entire array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::find
#include <iterator> // for std::begin, std::end
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

char alphabet(int N)
{
    char *dArray;
    dArray= new char[N+1];
    dArray[N]= '\0';
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int r = rand()%26;
        char letter='a'+r;
        cout<<"dArray["<<i<<"] is: "<< letter<<endl;
        dArray[i]= letter;
    }
    
    return *dArray;
}

int main()
{
    int arrayN;
    int N;
    printf("enter the number of elements: ");
    cin >> N; 
    char *dArray = alphabet(N);
    for (int i=0; i<=N; i++)
    {
        cout<<"dArray["<<i<<"] "<<dArray[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw owning pointer, use `std::string` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The return type of `alphabet` now is char, not char*

Comment: _I dont really understand pointers and how to call and create dynamic arrays_ Good, do what @Jarod42 recommends and save yourself a lot of heartache.

Comment: In English, `return *dArray;` means return the first character in the array `dArray`. The pointer to the array is lost and without that pointer it's next to impossible to free the array. This is called a memory leak.

Comment: Future bug: Any time you see a `<=` in the exit condition of a loop iterating a container, odds are really good you are looking at a bug. Check the range of `i` in `for (int i=0; i<=N; i++)` to make certain you aren't going one past the end.

Comment: This way of writing a user-level application in C++ is highly discouraged in this day and age of C++.  As mentioned, use `std::vector<char>`, `std::string`, or similar.   In many (if not most) code reviews that are done, you will need to justify why you're using `new[]` instead of using `std::vector`, and there better be a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have declared the return type wrong. it should be `char *`

```
char *alphabet(int N) // <<<<====
{
    char *dArray;
    dArray= new char[N+1];
    dArray[N]= '\0';
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int r = rand()%26;
        char letter='a'+r;
        cout<<"dArray["<<i<<"] is: "<< letter<<endl;
        dArray[i]= letter;
    }
    
    return dArray; // <<<<<<=====
}
```

but much better would be `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`

Comment: @DandyApe dont forget to release the dynamic array. `delete [] dArray;` inside the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid raw owning pointers, and prefer `std::string`.

Using std, you might do something like:

```
std::string random_letters(std::size_t N, std::mt19937& rnd)
{
    std::string res(N, '\0');

    const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 25);

    std::generate(res.begin(), res.end(), [&](){ return alphabet[dist(rnd)]; });

    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G3a5Wc7P4)